# Kohana database config settings for ORM

Tags: php, kohana

How do I select which database config my ORM should use? The docs only mentions how to setup the config and select it when using the pure database method. Not when using an ORM.

Here is my current config:

**controller**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $members = ORM::factory('user');
        $members->where('first_name', '=', 'Peter')->find_all();
        $memCount = $members->count_all();          
        $this->response->body('Count: ' . $memCount);
    }

} // End Welcome
```

**Model**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends ORM
{   
    protected $_primary_key = 'UserId';
}
```

**Config** (This is located in application/config/database.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array
(
    'local' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'database'   => 'dbname',
            'username'   => 'username',
            'password'   => '*******',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
    ),
    'remote' => array(
        'type'       => 'pdo',
        'connection' => array(
            'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kohana',
            'username'   => 'root',
            'password'   => '***',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
    ),
);
```

I just want the ORM to use the `local` database. How do I do this? Right now I get the error: `Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Dont forget to set `default` DB settings for other models. You can use something like `$config['default'] = $config['local']; return $config;` in config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Kowser said, for Database::instance() to return a connection using the 'local' database group use Database::$default = 'local';

If you want to let a class use a specific database group that is not Database::$default.
Then in your class definition set $_db_group to the database config group like so:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends ORM
{
    protected $_db_group = 'local';
    protected $_primary_key = 'UserId';
}
```

This way you can set Database::$default to 'remote' and only objects of that class will use the 'local' connection.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you know that, Kohana uses `default` by default. If you want something different by default, add this line to your `bootstrap.php`:

```
Database::$default = "local";
```

This should do the trick.